# Xamarin Forms: Animations with OpacityProperty BindableProperty

Tags: animation, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, converters

In the ViewModel I have a dependency property called IsButtonVisible, either true or false.

In the View layer I have this layout that I need to show or hide, depending on the value of IsButtonVisible. But I don't just want to show or hide it abruptly, I want to *smoothly fade it in and out.*

I read online that the way to do it is via events, e.g. to fade the control to 0% or 100% over 3 seconds:

```
await image.FadeTo(0, 3000);
await image.FadeTo(1, 3000);
```

But now I want to do it via databinding. The old code was:

```
MyControl.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsButtonVisible");
```

Now I need to use smooth opacity instead, the farthest I could reach is:

```
MyControl.SetBinding(OpacityProperty, "IsButtonVisible", BindingMode.OneWay, new MyButtonConverter()););

public class MyButtonConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return 1; // 100%; visible

        return 0; // 0%; invisible
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Problem is it's as abrupt as visibility is involved.

Is there a way I can use animation somewhere, whether in the databinding statement or inside the converter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not what to add the View (animation) logic inside your ViewModel as that will break its independance of the ContentPage/View/..., testing becomes difficult, etc, ... (lots of SO Q/As regarding this already).

So lets assume that your ViewModel exposes a property change event, an assignable callback Command or Action, or a System.Reactive subject (my personal choice), etc... for your `IsButtonVisible` property that you can attach to in your `View` (not the ViewModel), something like this in the ContentPage .ator:

```
InitializeComponent();
BindingContext = viewModel = new AnimPageViewModel();
viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
```

Now when the `IsButtonVisible` changes you can run your animation, this example just toggles the Opacity back and forth each time that property changes.

```
async void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsButtonVisible")
    {
        await animateButton
            .FadeTo(
                Math.Abs(animateButton.Opacity) > double.Epsilon ? 0 : 1,
                2000,
                Math.Abs(animateButton.Opacity) < double.Epsilon ? Easing.CubicIn : Easing.CubicOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks very much.